# Converting nvarchar (epoch time) to datetime in t-Sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to convert an Nvarchar(510) column to human readable date time. The column EPOCHDATE is a bigint value.

When I run this:

```
select  
    dateadd(ms, 1427213353825%(3600*24*1000), 
        dateadd(day, 1427213353825/(3600*24*1000), '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0'))
```

I get back the date in human readable form. 1427213353825 is the EPOCHDATE value from the first row.

BUT when I run it using the column I get

> The conversion of the nvarchar value '1427213353825' overflowed an int column.

How can I fix this? I didn't create the table so I don't think I can change that column.

Comment: Are you explicitly casting your nvarchar column?   Try casting it to bigint,

Answer (score 0):

Converting the epoch column to a bigint gets around that error.

```
DECLARE @blah TABLE (epoch NVARCHAR(512));
INSERT INTO @blah VALUES ('1427213353825');

SELECT
  DATEADD(ms, CAST(epoch AS BIGINT) %(3600*24*1000), 
    DATEADD(DAY, CAST(epoch AS BIGINT)/(3600*24*1000), '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0'))
FROM @blah
```